# Function returns string instead of dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dictionary

I have a package called "random-words" and it generates a random word every day.

This is the main program:

```py
from random_word import RandomWords

r = RandomWords()
word = r.word_of_the_day()
print( word )
```

And this is the output:

```py
'{"word": "daedal", "definations": [{"source": "gcide", "text": "Cunningly or ingeniously formed or working; skillful; artistic; ingenious.", "note": null, "partOfSpeech": "adjective"}, {"source": "gcide", "text": "Crafty; deceitful.", "note": null, "partOfSpeech": "adjective"}]}'
```

I know this is a simple question but I could find anything on the web except pages using `exec()`
The return type is string and i can't use it like a dictionary. How do i tackle with that? I tried using `exec()`, `eval()` or converting to `list()`, `dict()` or even `set()` but nothing worked.

This is the code when using `exec()`:

```py
from random_word import RandomWords

r = RandomWords()
word = exec(r.word_of_the_day())
```

And here is the error message:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\filip\Desktop\test_words.py", line 4, in <module>
    word = exec(r.word_of_the_day())
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'null' is not defined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use json.loads https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

```
import json

string_val = '{"word": "daedal", "definations": [{"k":"v"}]}'
dict_val = json.loads(string_val)

print(dict_val['word'])
```

outputs

```
daedal
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :). I thought of json but didn't know how to use it correctly.